# Copying 2D array in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to copy a 2D array into another array. However, I am running into a strange problem where the first row does not get printed by my function. However, values are there since when I print the first row separately it does get printed.

This is my perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use UNIVERSAL 'isa';

#Function to print the contents of an array
sub printArray {
    my ($vHash) = @_;
    if (isa($vHash, 'ARRAY')) {
        foreach my $el (@$vHash) {
            print "A: $el\n";
            printArray($el);
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
    return;
}

my @array = "";
my @line1 = (1, 2, 3);
my @line2 = (3, 4, 5);
my @line3 = (6, 7, 8);

#Creating a 2D array
@array = (\@line1, \@line2, \@line3);

my @array2 = "";
my $row_size = @array;
print "ROW SIZE: $row_size\n";
my $column_size = @{$array[0]};
print "COL Size: $column_size\n\n\n";

#Copying over the 2D array...element by element
for (my $i=0; $i<$row_size; ++$i) {
    for (my $j=0; $j<$column_size; ++$j) {
        $array2[$i][$j] = $array[$i][$j];
    }
}

print "\n\nORIG ARRAY\n\n";
printArray(\@array);
print "\n\nCOPY ARRAY\n";
printArray(\@array2);

print "\n\n";

#Printing the first row separately
foreach my $ele (@{$array2[0]}) {
    print "V: $ele\n";
}
```

This is the output of the program:

```
ROW SIZE: 3
COL Size: 3




ORIG ARRAY

A: ARRAY(0x65b110)
A: 1
A: 2
A: 3
A: ARRAY(0x65b170)
A: 3
A: 4
A: 5
A: ARRAY(0x65b1d0)
A: 6
A: 7
A: 8


COPY ARRAY
A:                                                     #WHY THIS IS MISSING
A: ARRAY(0x6d1f00)
A: 3
A: 4
A: 5
A: ARRAY(0x6d1f50)
A: 6
A: 7
A: 8


V: 1                                                  #THESE VALUES ARE COMING FINE
V: 2
V: 3
```

I am really confused as to what am I doing wrong here!! Why the function printArray not printing first row? Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks,
Newbie

Comment: The use of `UNIVERSAL::isa` like this is deprecated. You should `use Scalar::Util 'reftype'` and then `if (ref $vHash and reftype $vHash eq 'ARRAY') { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program, especially before asking for help with your code.

Had you done so in this case you would have been warned that you couldn't assign to `$array2[0][0]` etc.

You have initialised your arrays using

```
@array2 = "";
```

which creates an array with one element equal to the null string `("")`. Now that it has a value, Perl cannot auto-vivify an array reference in the first element for you, so your assignments fail.

All of this would be apparent if you had enabled `strict`. The error messages would explain exactly what was going wrong.

There is no need to initialise a new array if you want it empty, but the correct way to do so would be

```
@array = ();
```

Comment: OMG...thanks a lot! I wasted so much time on this...didnt realize that use strict and use warnings are turned off...thanks for your explanation too.

Answer (score 5):

By the way, you do not need to write copy functions like this one.

```
use Storable qw(dclone);
my @array2 = @{ dclone(\@array) };
```

`dclone` would make a deep copy of any perl data structure.

Moreover, if you only need to print this data, you could just use `Data::Dumper` for that.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@array), "\n"
```